# Curl don't work with ip but work with interface name

Tags: unix, curl, proxy, raspberry-pi

I have some usb intefaces like item below:

```
usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::9ab9:64dd:7e97:41da  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 5a:45:bc:ae:48:fc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 341  bytes 89768 (87.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 471  bytes 43750 (42.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

When i use command it works fine:

```
curl --interface usb0 https://google.com
```

But when i use ip - it doesn't work:

```
curl --interface 192.168.1.100 https://google.com
```

Do you have ideas why and how to fix it?

I expect both ways must work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more information. What exactly means "it doesn't work"? Show the error message or the unexpected result. Show the IP addresses of all interfaces. Why do you need to specify the interface? Did you check what's happening with a network sniffer (e.g. `wireshark` or `tcpdump`)?